# Many many thanks

Tags: mathematics

The alphametic

MANY + MANY = THANKS

has no solutions in base 10. How many more "MANYs" must I add before it  has a solution?

Comment: I am new here and with puzzles but if you use T=0, you can find a solution with 2 "MANYs". is that valid?

Comment: @gustavovelascoh I believe we usually assume that leading zeroes are not permitted as they are rather improper.

Comment: This would make a great codegolf.  Take two inputs (like "MANY" and "THANKS" and output the minimum number of "MANY"s to make "THANKS".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From

> 1814400

possible permutations of letters `AHKMNSTY` and  digits 0-9 (`P(10,8)`), just

> 759

are valid for the problem `n * MANY = THANKS`. This is, just those were `THANKS/MANY` is an integer.

After removing those solutions where `T=0 (THANKS <= 99999)`, there are 727 left from which the minimum n is

> 17 (3 solution already given in another answer: (8567, 8569, 8576))

**BONUS:**

The maximum `n` is 7815 for `MANY=0123`. If `M=0 or MANY <= 999` is not valid, the maximum will be `n=935` for `MANY=1027`

*csv files with solutions:*

- 318 solutions without   `M or T = 0` [non_zeros.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PGKfVNlopbLCu38LIfqLgxTHc5rIHenP)
- 759 solutions including `M or T = 0` [with_zeros.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AGuJd3Moxb1X2pDLxm97GKErPOgwQXMa)

Comment: Do you have any proof for all these assertions? I'm guessing you used a machine to get them?

Comment: I did it. Isn't that valid?

Comment: Well, it's hard for anyone else to judge if this answer is correct or not.

Comment: ok, I will try to detail on the process

Answer (score 10):

I think you need (in base ten):

> 15 more manys (17 all together)

There are three solutions:

> A=5 H=4 K=3 M=8 N=6 S=9 T=1 Y=7 because $8567\times17=145639$,
>  A=5 H=4 K=7 M=8 N=6 S=3 T=1 Y=9 because $8569\times17=145673$, and
>  A=5 H=4 K=9 M=8 N=7 S=2 T=1 Y=6 because $8576\times17=145792$.

Or

> Zero more: 
> $7493\times2=014986$ 
> A=4 H=1 K=8 M=7 N=9 S=6 Y=3 T=0 
> $8746\times2=17492$ 
> A=7 H=1 K=9 M=8 N=4 S=2 Y=6

Comment: Can you justify this?

Comment: Edited for justification.

Comment: That wasn't the necessary justification.  Anyone can do arithmetic.  The real question is, do you have a proof of minimality?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 How should I prove it? Won't the OP know the answer and check it?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 that's like asking a crossword solver to prove there are no other words which fit. I proved it with a C code but there is already a good answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane Poor analogy. Would you say the same if someone posted an answer with 7815 "many"s? In mathematics problems, proving minimality is often an important aspect.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, no, because 7815 is not the correct answer. The question implies a minimum.

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly! If the question implies a minimum, then a fully correct answer must prove that it's the minimum.

Comment: @Randal'Thor then should I post my (not the best) C code as an answer?

Comment: @WeatherVane Sure. I'm generally not a fan of computer-generated answers, but it may be necessary for this puzzle in order to prove minimality without ridiculous amounts of time and calculation.

Comment: Could you define "ridiculous amounts"?

Comment: I still don't know how to justify this...

Comment: I think there should be a formal math approach where you can describe the set of solutions that fulfill the constraints. For example, "if S is an odd number, Y must be an odd number too" but expressed in format terms. I guess this has something to do with sets theory or discrete mathematics or abstract proofs, things that I don't know. But would be nice if someone could share it, though.

Comment: I have minimal now, adding 0 many's gives you an answer.

Comment: Yes edited the other one took me some time to find, edited in now.

Answer (score 4):

The question was already answered by @Duck, but here is a (not very well-crafted or efficient) C program which tests increasing numbers of **MANY** until a solution (in fact three) is found.

Program output:

> x   * MANY = THANKS
>  17 * 8567 = 145639
>  17 * 8569 = 145673
>  17 * 8576 = 145792
>  3 results found
>  Took ~ 0.37 seconds

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int used[10];
int result;
int rep = 2;
int M, A, N, Y, T, H, K, S, AN;

void check(int many)
{
    for(T=1; T<10; T++) {
        if(used[T] == 0) {
            used[T] = 1;
            int Tval = T * 100000;
            for(H=0; H<10; H++) {
                if(used[H] == 0) {
                    used[H] = 1;
                    int Hval = Tval + H * 10000;
                    for(K=0; K<10; K++) {
                        if(used[K] == 0) {
                            used[K] = 1;
                            int Kval = Hval + K * 10;
                            for(S=0; S<10; S++) {
                                if(used[S] == 0) {
                                    if(Kval + AN + S == many) {
                                        printf("%d * %d%d%d%d = %d%d%d%d%d%d\n", rep, 
                                                M,A,N,Y,  T,H,A,N,K,S);
                                        result++;
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                            used[K] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    used[H] = 0;
                }
            }
            used[T] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    clock_t tstart = clock();
    printf("x  * MANY = THANKS\n");

    while(result == 0) {
        for(M=1; M<10; M++) {
            used[M] = 1;
            int Mval = M * 1000;
            for(A=0; A<10; A++) {
                if(used[A] == 0) {
                    used[A] = 1;
                    int Aval = Mval + A * 100;
                    for(N=0; N<10; N++) {
                        if(used[N] == 0) {
                            used[N] = 1;
                            int Nval = Aval + N * 10;
                            AN = (A * 10 + N) * 100;    // for "thanks"
                            for(Y=0; Y<10; Y++) {
                                if(used[Y] == 0) {
                                    used[Y] = 1;
                                    check((Nval + Y) * rep);
                                    used[Y] = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            used[N] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    used[A] = 0;
                }
            }
            used[M] = 0;
        }
        rep++;
    }
    printf("%d results found\n", result);
    double elapse = (double)(clock() - tstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Took ~ %.2f seconds\n", elapse);
    return 0;
}
```

So the answer is

> **15**

Answer (score 2):

I also coded this out, running it in python (you can even use change the words for other similar puzzles, they're global variables, I used "CAT" and "DOG" to test the logic worked for trivial examples.

I would be very interested in a rigorous proof, but given how complex the setup is to express in mathematical logic I suspect there isn't an easy one.

````
import math as maths
import sys

def build_coding(iter_num):
    return_coding = {}
    for i,char in enumerate(word[0]):
        return_coding[char] = iter_num%10
        iter_num -= iter_num%10
        iter_num = int(iter_num/10)
    return return_coding


def attempt_codings(iteration_number,multi_number):
    first_coding = build_coding(iteration_number)
    num[0] = word_to_num(first_coding,word[0])#aka get word 0 as a num (num 0)
    if len(str(num[0])) != len(word[0]):
        return ""
    num[1] = num[0]*(multi_number)#word 1, as a num (num 1)
    if len(str(num[1])) != len(word[1]):
        return ""

    second_coding = {}
    for i,char in enumerate(str(num[1])):#build second coding by matching letters in word 1 to num 1
        second_coding[word[1][i]] = int(char)
    for quay in first_coding.keys():
        if quay in second_coding.keys():
            if first_coding[quay] != second_coding[quay]:#if a key in one exists in either
                return ""
    end_coding = {}
    for quay in first_coding.keys():
        if quay in end_coding:#if this key is double-coded
            if end_coding[quay] != first_coding[quay]:#and the double doesn't match
                return ""
        end_coding[quay] = first_coding[quay]

    for quay in second_coding.keys():
        if quay in end_coding:#if this key is double-coded
            if end_coding[quay] != second_coding[quay]:#and the double doesn't match
                return ""
        end_coding[quay] = second_coding[quay]
    uniquevals = []
    for quay in end_coding.keys():
        if end_coding[quay] in uniquevals:#if we already have a match for this value
            return ""
        else:
            uniquevals.append(end_coding[quay])
    return end_coding

def word_to_num(coding,word):
    num = 0
    for i,char in enumerate(word):
        num += maths.pow(10,len(word)-i-1)*coding[char]
    return int(num)

word = ["",""]
word[0] = "MANY"
word[1] = "THANKS"
num = ["",""]
for i in range(10000):#ways of coding the first word, including invalid ones like '00010'
    for j in range(20):#number of the first word to add (aka multiplication)
        coding = attempt_codings(i,j)
        if coding != "":
            print("~~~A SOLUTION:")
            print("CODING IS :: {}".format(coding))
            print("{} becomes :: {}".format(word[0],word_to_num(coding,word[0])))
            print("{} becomes :: {}".format(word[1],word_to_num(coding,word[1])))
            print("{} * {} = {}".format(word_to_num(coding,word[0]),j,word_to_num(coding,word[1])))
            sys.exit("Solution found")

```
````